# Don't resend invitation after each update of an event O365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I use the graph api for sync my calendar software with the O365 calendar.
After each update of the event in my software, i send to O365 and the graphAPI resend an invitation to all attendee in this event. have u a solution for don't send any notification, invitation or other after an update of the event ?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, it is not yet possible to do this via Graph API. Would you consider upvoting this feature request on the M365 Developer Platform: [Ability to update or create an event without sending a notification email to attendees](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/ability-to-update-or-create-an-event-without-sending-a/idi-p/2335070) so that it can be looked into?